# Cannot set indicator style for UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to init a `UIActivityIndicatorView` like so:

```
var indicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.white

    lazy fileprivate var loadingActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: indicatorStyle)
        indicator.hidesWhenStopped = false
        return indicator
    }()
```

This lives in a custom `UIButton`. I have the style set as a `var` so the color can be set before init. However I am getting the error:

`Instance member indicatorStyle cannot be used on type CustomButton.` What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style inside the constructor. You can try this, it works for me:

```
lazy var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        var ai = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        ai = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
        ai.hidesWhenStopped = false
        return ai
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

member variable indicatorStyle can not be used in other member variable declared like this

```
let  indicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle = .White
let  indicator : UIActivityIndicatorView =   UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: indicatorStyle)
```

And use this in a function that would be nice

```
func  test() -> Void {
     let  indicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle = .White
     let  indicator : UIActivityIndicatorView =    UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: indicatorStyle)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd have to be `self.indicatorStyle` inside a lazy block like that

```
var indicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle = .white

private lazy var loadingActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
    let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: self.indicatorStyle)
    indicator.hidesWhenStopped = false
    return indicator
}()
```